# Check if PXN is enabled?

Tags: mobile, android, protection

I am looking for a way to check on a mobile device if PXN(Privileged Execute-Never) Protection Mechanism is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot check that because the processor registers are encrypted. The SP register is also encrypted from android 4.4.4 and on.